# Cache tableView cell data

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, caching

In my application, I want to cache the displayed data in tableview so that whenever the application starts or if the internet connection isn't there, my tableview should be able to display the cached old data [not completely but say 10 old cached cells].

What I'm displaying in individual cells is an object of one of the 8 classes I'm defining. So in my case I'll have to create 8 tables in order to store these objects.

Can anybody suggest any efficient way of achieving this?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little hint: Maintain plist(XML) file with NSDictionary as item; just like a info.plist file

Answer (score 0):

Write data to SQLite database and read on start. It is quick, easy and efficient. This might help you: http://www.mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/